# Ubuntu 18.04 suddenly having issues with ONE specific 802.11ac wifi network, no internet after 5-10 seconds

Tags: networking, wireless, internet

Ubuntu 18.04 has worked fine with my home network for months.  Suddenly something has changed and Ubuntu 18.04 can only access the internet for the first 5-10 seconds after connecting to my home network.  If I disconnect and reconnect I get another 5 or 10 seconds of internet and then nothing.  Other computers (windows) have no issues with this network.  The Ubuntu 18.04 machine doesn't have any issues as far as I can tell with any other wireless networks.  I've reset the router, "forgotten" the connection in Ubuntu and re-added. My home router has 5ghz and 2.4ghz channels and the problem is identical with either connection, about 5-10 seconds of internet when I first connect and then nothing.  Wifi chipset is intel 8265 or 8275 (on HP spectre x360 2017).

I've tried manually entering dns 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4, doesn't help.

When internet is not working Ubuntu still shows it's connected to the router.  I cannot ping 8.8.8.8 or 8.8.4.4 when the internet stops like this. If I disconnect and reconnect then I can ping those IP's for that 5-10 second window.

Router is a ZYXEL-C3000Z and this computer with ubuntu 18.04 had worked flawlessly on it for months.

When the internet drops like this I can still synergy onto other computers (windows) and control them so I'm still connected to the router and connected locally.

Any ideas?  This is really a strange one.

Comment: Might be this issue: https://forum.manjaro.org/t/linux-firmware-201907-breaks-iwlwifi/96529/11

Comment: I am seeing "iwlwifi Microcode SW error detected. Restarting 0x2000000."

I set up another 802.11ac router and it seems to work fine with that one.